# What is strong naming and how do I strong name a binary?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I heard somewhere that I need to strong name my binaries before I distribute them. Any ideas what this is?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Eric Lippert [posted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/whats-the-difference-part-five-certificate-signing-vs-strong-naming) about strong signing assemblies:

> The purpose of a strong name is solely to ensure that **when you load an assembly by name, you are loading exactly the assembly you think you are loading**. You say "I want to load Frobber, version 4, that came from FooCorp". The strong name gear ensures that you actually load precisely that DLL, and not another assembly called Frobber, version 4, that came from Dr. Evil Enterprises. You can then set security policy which says "if I have an assembly from FooCorp on my machine, fully trust it." These scenarios are the only by-design purposes of strong names.

Comment: Consider providing a relevant snipped from this post, in case the link breaks.

Comment: Hmm, poor answer: that doesn't answer the second part of the question ("how do I strong name a binary").

Answer (score 3):

In short strong named assemblies are signed with a certificate. They play a role for the CAS (Code Access Security): what the assembly has the right to do or not to do.

[Edit] as some of you pointed out: it is really advised to create strong assemblies as they will be more robust against attacks like introducing foreign malicious code into your application if you wrote some plug-in mechanism for example.

This way you can limit what the 3rdparty plug-ins are allowed to do in the context of your application.

Comment: There's a lot more : What about the GAC ? What about "assembly spoofing" ? etc...

Comment: Strong-named assemblies are NOT signed with a certificate. Strong-named assemblies are signed with a strong-name key. Certificate-signed assemblies are signed with a certificate. If you do not understand the difference, see my article linked above.

Comment: If I have an application that consists of a normal executable and a DLL which it calls, do I just strong name the DLL, or do I strong name both the exe and the DLL?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the second part of the question: [How to: Sign an Assembly with a Strong Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx)

> #### To create and sign an assembly with a strong name by using Visual Studio
>
> In **Solution Explorer**, open the shortcut menu for the solution, and then choose **Properties**.
>
> Choose the **Signing** tab.
>
> Select the **Sign the assembly** box.
>
> In the **Choose a strong name key file** box, choose , and then navigate to the key file. To create a new key file, choose  and enter its name in the **Create Strong Name Key** dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [MSDN magazine article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150114100722/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163583.aspx) useful when learning about strong naming assemblies.

Comment: The link is broken; it takes you to a list of issues.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think I've found a live link via the wayback archive.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about .NET assemblies, here are [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx).