# What is a "STRONG NAME" in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, strongname

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is strong naming and how do I strong name a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436879/what-is-strong-naming-and-how-do-i-strong-name-a-binary)

Actually, yesterday I attended an interview. There they asked me 1 question about strong name. I was not able to guess what it is? please explain about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> A strong name consists of the assembly's identity — its simple text name, version number, and culture information (if provided) — plus a public key and a digital signature.

You can use strong naming to ensure that when you load a DLL you get exactly the DLL you were expecting and not some other DLL that happens to have the same name.

Answer (score 12):

A 'strongly named' assembly is one that has been signed with a key to ensure its uniqueness (for example, in the GAC). See here for more details:

[Creating and Using Strong Named Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwb8f617(v=VS.80).aspx)